# Creating a Virtual USB Device with a Pico - Need Guidance

Tags: audio, usb, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I am currently working on a project where I need to create a virtual USB device on a host device using a Pico microcontroller. However, I am facing difficulties in understanding the process and I couldn't find any relevant information or resources on how to achieve this.

I have attempted to utilize various USB modules, but I am struggling to comprehend how to set the vendor ID, type ID, and other necessary parameters. I have referred to the documentation, but I couldn't find any specific details on creating a custom USB device.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in this matter. Thank you in advance for your help!

PS: This project uses circutpython

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in more detail? What software on the host will be communicating with the Pico and how 'custom' do you need it to be - what exactly should be different for the user compared to connecting a stock Pico flashed with CircuitPython?

Comment: usb sound card custom

Comment: Could you include some code samples to show us what you're doing and what errors you're encountering?

Comment: the thing is, i dont know how, thats why im asking